# A Page without the tab Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want a specific page without the tabbed page. I want to remove the tabbed page. However when I use this code it removes the navigation.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) from Xamarin:

It seems you need to create a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) for your page and set `ParentViewController.TabBarController.TabBar.Hidden = true` in `ViewWillAppear()`

Comment: Hi thank you for your response! However, I don't still quite get it. Could you please elaborate?